# Display different colored content detail for each option from the dropdown in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I wanted to display the content with different color when user selected an option. For example on the dropdown list, there's three option for the items. If user selects on Confirmed in Status placeholder, the content will display "Confirmed" in green and when user selects Not Confirmed, the item will display the wording "Not Confirmed" in Red. If user select "Confirmed and Shipped", the color will show Yellow. How do I get it to work? I'm new to Angular. I have tried so many ways but it won't work.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Status" [formControl]="statusTypeFilter">
    <mat-option value="1">Confirmed</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">Not Confirmed</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="3">Confirmed and Shipped</mat-option>
</mat-form-field>


<div class="table-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="ItemConfirmationList" multiTemplateDataRows matSort matSortActive="no">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="StatusName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort- header>Status</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.StatusName }}</td>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that i did:

- we stored the value selected from the dropdown in a variable
- for each row in our table, we checked the status against this variable and in
  case of a match, we set the appropriate class

appropriate **html**:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Status</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
            {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<!-- <p>You selected: {{selected}}</p> -->
<hr/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> Item </td>
                <td> Status </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngFor='let pickedItem of sampleItems; let idx = index'>
                <tr [ngClass]="setColor(pickedItem.status, idx)">
                    <td> {{pickedItem.item}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <span *ngIf='pickedItem.status == 1'> Confirmed </span>
            <span *ngIf='pickedItem.status == 2'> Not Confirmed </span>
            <span *ngIf='pickedItem.status == 3'> Confirmed and Shipped </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

appropriate **ts**:

```
setColor(statusVal, idx){
  let returnedClass:string ='defaultClass';
  (statusVal == this.selected && statusVal ===1) ? returnedClass = 'confirmedClass' : 'defaultClass';
  (statusVal == this.selected && statusVal ===2) ? returnedClass = 'notConfirmedClass' : 'defaultClass';
  (statusVal == this.selected && statusVal ===3) ? returnedClass = 'shippedClass' : 'defaultClass';
  return returnedClass;
}
```

appropriate **css**:

```
.confirmedClass { color:green;}
.notConfirmedClass { color:red;}
.shippedClass { color:orange;}
.defaultClass { color:#000;}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5a8uyt)

Comment: it's a bit different. I want it to display the word Confirmed in red  when the Status Confirmed is being selected from the dropdown list

Comment: Hi @IvanaMica, updated the stackblitz and answer after your comment, kindly confirm

Comment: Can you remove the item? I just want to display the status. Thank you

Comment: yes @Umesh, and didn't get any appreciation or votes from him/her... :(

Answer (score 0):

You should create 3 CSS styles, each one of them for different status

CSS

```
.confirmed {
  color: green;
}
.not-confirmed {
  color: red
}
```

Then in your template, use `[ngClass]` to apply the CSS

```
<td [ngClass]="{ 'confirmed': status === 'Confirmed', 'not-confirmed': status === 'Not Confirmed', 'confirm-shipped': status === 'Confirmed and Shipped' }"
 mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
   {{element.StatusName}}
</td>
```

PS: I assumed that you are storing dropdown value in `status` variable

Comment: how do I see that my dropdown value is storing in  'status' variable? But the value is stored in numbers

Comment: you can console log the status variable which you are using to store drop down option value. you can change the value of `status` in ngClass to numbers if the type is number - `'confirmed': status === 1`

Comment: I don't know when you say variable store in `status` not in `StatusName`. It's your code and you should know about it. We are here to help you sort your issues and not writing code for you. Hope you understand. I assume you have enough understanding of angular and you must know what are variables and how does it work in angular.